# Boot2docker i/o timeout when opening a new terminal session in MacOs X

Tags: macos, docker, zsh, boot2docker

I've installed boot2docker under MacOs X. Everything works great.

But when the boot2docker vm is not running (like after a reboot), each terminal session takes a long time to start because of a timeout against the boot2docker endpoint.

```
Last login: Fri Dec 12 08:13:10 on console
2014/12/12 08:21:45 Get https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.15/images/json: dial tcp 192.168.59.103:2376: i/o timeout
2014/12/12 08:22:17 Get https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.15/containers/json?all=1: dial tcp     192.168.59.103:2376: i/o timeout
2014/12/12 08:22:50 Get https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.15/containers/json?all=1: dial tcp 192.168.59.103:2376: i/o timeout
```

Any thought on how to avoid this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not about programming.  Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: You appear to be using zsh — anything docker-related in your `~/.zshrc`? (besides environment variables)